# "Cannot complete this action. please try again" SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, error

When I create an item in the list, it always display error message

> Cannot complete this action. please try again

But other list works fine in the same site.

The ULS displays error message

> Application error when access /Lists/forum/NewForm.aspx, Error=Cannot complete this action. please try again.
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): 
>       Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. 
>       ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action. please try again 
>       ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.
>       please try again

but I don't know how to correct this problem

ULS as below:

> Application error when access /Lists/forum/NewForm.aspx, 
>       Error=Cannot complete this action. please try again.
>       at    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem
>       (String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafe... ec15169d-9ea9-c0ef-a741-53bc227dd828
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): 
>       Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. 
>       ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action. please try again 
>       ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action. 
>       please try again
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Bool...  ec15169d-9ea9-c0ef-a741-53bc227dd828

Comment: any event receivers?

Comment: @TiagoDuarte hi, I don't understand your question. This site is a migrated site by attach/detach, I think maybe the problem from database. I did not post all ULS logs. Do you need all ULS logs?

Comment: any additional info may help. also, if you have a dev farm with a copy of the DB you can enable custom errors and see the error on the spot. this is usually custom code messing around with Web.Update(), event receivers, etc. but can also be missing features, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This type of error occurs when you have delete something and do not updated.

For example if you have deleted one `custom view` and did not update list, and again you are trying to add a custom view with same title and get that view, then you will get this error.

If you have deleted the list or list item and did not update the list, and trying to add new item with same title, then below error occurs

> "Cannot complete action"

So, before trying to add new item make sure that it was updated.

Comment: Updating what, what are you talking about?

Comment: i meant list.update()

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your CAML query has all the closing slashes, especially after `FieldRef` Name like:

```
<FieldRef Name='ID' />
```

When I forgot to add that `/` before `>` I got the same error as you did.

Comment: In general - malformed CAML will cause this